# Constraint Jacobian vs Space Jacobian

Tags: kinematics, jacobian

In the context of the book "Modern Robotics" of Kevin Lynch, and in the context of closed-chain mechanisms, what's the difference between the constraint Jacobian and the space Jacobian?